# c# - How to save List of objects into a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a simple windows form application. Basically, I want to save the user's input of their ID number and name. I have a Person class:

```
class Person
{
    private string nric;
    private string name;

    public Person(string nric, string name)
    {
        this.nric = nric;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

And the .cs file:

```
    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Person> pList = new List<Person>();
        Person p1 = new Person(nric.Text, name.Text);
        pList.Add(p1);

        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("PersonFile.txt"))
        {
            foreach (Person p in pList)
            {
                tw.WriteLine(p);
            }
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

When I tried to run the codes, this is the output shown in the PersonFile.txt:

```
   Testing.Person
```

How do I make it such that the ID number and name would be displayed in the text file?

Comment: do you intend to load the file again at a later time?

Comment: @MongZhu yes actually

Comment: what is the reason for making the fields private? do you have public properties to access the values? or do you just to intend to use the constructor when loading the data? and you never access the values of `nric` and `name`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add "ToString" method.

```
class Person
{
    private string nric;
    private string name;

    public Person(string nric, string name)
    {
        this.nric = nric;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return $"{nric} {name}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd make use of the C# string formatting to make it look nicer `$"{nric} {name}"`

Comment: @Ralt, I agree with you;) Thanks

Comment: `ToString()` is a very bad option. It is useful only for debugging or displaying something on UI. https://stackoverflow.com/a/563859/6552578

Comment: @apocalypse I'm not agree with you in this situation.
I answered to explain the reason for appearing "Testing.Person"

Comment: @MiguelCosta: but in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44695674/6552578 you made a comment which says your solution (ToString) is better. IMO your solution is much worse.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
 tw.WriteLine(p);
```

simply calls `p.ToString()` and writes the returning string into your file. The default implementation of `ToString()` returns the name of the object's type.

One way to solve your issue is to overwrite `ToString()`:

```
class Person
{
    private string nric;
    private string name;

    public Person(string nric, string name)
    {
        this.nric = nric;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nric} {name}";
    }
}
```

---

If you actually want to save the list in a way you can later load it again, you may want to read about [serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/). There are easy ways to store and load objects in different formats (like xml, binary etc).

Answer (score 0):

override the toString() for the class

```
class Person
{
    private string nric;
    private string name;

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return name + " " + nric;
    }
}
```

then (no need to create StreamWriter):

```
File.WriteAllLines("PersonFile.txt", pList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just print the Type of the Object.

Try this:

```
Tw.WriteLine($"Id: {p.nric}, Name: {p.name}");
```

Comment: `nric` and `name` are `private`, so this won't compile.

Comment: Just add getters and setters and you are fine

Comment: @RenéVogt, formatting output in WriteLine method is more sensible solution than adding `ToString` override for that purpose alone (and serialization rules them both). And **very likely** `Person` class has properties Nric and Name, because it becomes black box otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can add function to `Person` class

```
public string getPerson()
{
    return this.nric + " "+ thisname;
}
```

and change

```
tw.WriteLine(p);
```

to

```
call tw.WriteLine(p.getPerson());
```

Comment: In my opinion, adding ToString is the best way.

Comment: c# naming convention is : `public string GetPerson()`. `Person` class as data structure shouldn't be responsible for formatted output, existance of GetPerson method in Person class is very questionable